# Passing data through nested components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am writing a page using Vue.js and am attempting some custom components. I've started with a very simple one:

```
Vue.component('single-field', {
    template: '<b>{{ key }}:</b> {{ value }}',
    props: ['key', 'value']
});
```

This works fine on its own: it is intended to take two values and return them in a  **key:** value format. Initially, when I was passing the value as an element from the Vue `data` object (specifically, `pickup.dateTime` it wasn't working. It's easier to show than explain:

```
<div id="app">
    <single-field key="Date & Time" value="pickup.dateTime"></single-field>
</div>
```

I was able to fix this by *binding* the value (notice the colon by value):

```
<single-field key="Date & Time" :value="pickup.dateTime"></single-field>
```

I then wrote a second component which is designed to take an object and a title and return each element of the object as a set of `<single-field>` components, with a title above them. Here is what I wrote:

```
Vue.component('field-block', {
    template: '<h2>{{title}}</h2>\
               <div v-for="(p-key, p-value) in parent">\
                   <single-field key="p-key" value="p-value"></single-field>\
               </div>',
    props: ['parent', 'title']
});
```

Now, I think there must be something wrong with the way I am binding (or not binding?) which is causing the data to be displayed in a strange way. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <single-field key="DateTime" :value="pickup.dateTime"></single-field>
    <single-field key="Name" :value="pickup.name"></single-field>
    <field-block title="Address" :parent="pickup.address"></field-block>
</div>
```

The field `pickup.address` is an object, so I was hoping that the component would iterate through the elements and return them as single fields, but what it's currently doing is just returning the variable names, like **p-key:** p-value. I tried doing a bind on both of them in the component definition (on both because they are now both variables being passed whereas previously I was using a static string for the `key` field):

```
<div v-for="(p-key, p-value) in parent">
    <single-field :key="p-key" :value="p-value"></single-field>
</div>
```

But what this returns is **NaN:** NaN, and I can't figure out why it would do that. I don't fully understand the bind operation, but I expect that it only binds to data in the `data` option when defining the view, which is not where `p-key` and `p-value` are defined. How would I get the variables to 'carry through' from the outer component to the inner ones? Thanks.

Comment: Beware, as 'key' is a reserved property name: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I've adjusted my code to replace all instances of ```key``` with ```s-key```. The behaviour is the same, but thank you for saving me potential trouble down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this one was tricky.

Several problems with your code:
Your components should have only one root element. So pack your components into a `<div>`.

Then, `-` is not a valid character to put into a javascript variable name. So you can't write `(p-key, p-value) in parent`, write something else, like `(pKey, pValue) in parent`.

On the other hand, html properties are not case-sensitive, so you should actually write key-name (for example) instead of keyName, but only for the property **names**. This limitation does apply only in your html files (not in your string templates).

Finally, here is a working js-fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/6juwLd3b/

Additionally, I would advise you that you look at your console while developing. Many error where displayed that could have lead you to a working version.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's fixed it! Honestly though, using Chrome, not a single error in the console. Where were you looking to find them?

Comment: Yeah, chrome as well. That's strange, as Vue should have notified you at least about the single root element problem (except if you are using Vue1, where it's not required).